# When to put jar's into the root of the ear and when to put them into the lib folder

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, jar

I have an ear where some jar's are in the root of the ear while some other jar's are inside the lib folder. That means something like the following:

```
myApplication.ear
  | myOtherApplication1.jar
  | lib
    | commons-lang-2.4.jar
    | myOtherApplication2.jar
```

This is achieved with the maven-ear-plugin.

Now I am wondering: When to put which jar where? Can't I just put everything inside the lib folder? Why would I put something in the root?

Comment: @Ivan This question is about an ear, not a war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard is that ejb jars are placed in the root directory and everything else is in `lib`. I guess that ejb jars are not properly picked up when you put them into `lib`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need any jar only for that particular module  and  not for other module then you can add those jars under that particular application jar lib folder or else If you want some jars for all application then add it under root ear